# El logo en mi navbar no carga en otras paginas

Tags: php, html, navbar, img, headers

Estoy tratando de agregar un logo a mi `navbar`, pero el logo no carga en otras paginas, solo en la principal.

A continuación, el codigo:

```
  <a class="navbar-brand text-white logo h3 align-self-center" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>">
    <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </a>
```

Puse la imagen en la carpeta `assets/img/logo.png`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que se ve es esto...

En la pagina principal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando le doy en "Nosotros":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ves a lo seguro. Coge y cuando veas el logo pulsa el botón derecho sobre el y te aparecerá un menú contextual con una de las opciones que pondrá algo asi como "Copiar enlace **de la imagen**", y luego vas y lo pegas en el atributo `src=` del elemento `<img` donde lo tienes ahora, y de esta forma seguro que lo verás en todas partes.  Si mucho me apuras, como el enlace será completo, le quitas la parte del nombre de dominio solo y te servirá igual.  Ejemplo:  `https://midominio.com/ruta/a/assets/img/logo.png` lo puedes dejar así: `/ruta/a/assets/img/logo.png`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que **index.php** y **about.php** están en rutas diferentes con referencia a **header.php**. Te sugiero que revises las rutas que estás usando para incluir o requerir **header.php** dentro de **about.php**.

Si no estoy muy perdido, **index.php** debe tener la ruta:

`./template-principal/header.php` *Está en views e ingresa a template-principal*

y **about.php** debería tener la ruta:

`../template-principal/header.php` *Sale de principal e ingresa a template-principal*